# In R, "Merge" seems to perform intersection, I need a Union of data frames

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

```
> cDates
# A tibble: 4 x 2
    week ClosedPR
  <date>    <int>
1 2017-01-09        1
2 2017-02-06        1
3 2017-05-22        1
4         NA       72
> oDates
# A tibble: 22 x 2
     week OpenPR
   <date>  <int>
1 2016-09-05      1
2 2016-09-12      1
3 2016-10-10      2
4 2016-12-19      1
5 2017-01-02      1
6 2017-01-09      1
7 2017-01-16      1
8 2017-01-23      2
9 2017-02-20      3
10 2017-03-06      2
# ... with 12 more rows
```

When I perform a "merge", I get the intersection of the data:

```
        week OpenPR ClosedPR
1 2017-01-09      1        1
2 2017-05-22      3        1
3       <NA>     27       72
```

What I'd like is the union of *all* the data not just the entries with common dates in "week".
How can I do this?

Comment: Consider investigating the `all`, `all.x`, and `all.y` arguments in [`?merge`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html)

Comment: Adding "all=TRUE" did the trick!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `merge`, perhaps use `full_join` from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(cDates, oDates, by = "week")
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if it mentioned some pros/cons of this approach.